# Adapting generic code to different size of linked list in C

Tags: c, linked-list

For a programming assignment, we've been asked to read in some data from a text file and populate a linked list with the data. Here is the example code we've been given:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <assert.h>

#define MAX_INPUT 20
#define EXTRA_CHARS 2

typedef struct listNode
{
   int data;
   struct listNode * next;
} ListNode;

typedef ListNode * ListNodePtr;

int main()
{
   ListNodePtr head, new, current, previous, next;
   unsigned listSize;

   int i, anInt;
   char str[MAX_INPUT];

   listSize = 0;
   head = NULL;

   while (fgets(str, MAX_INPUT+EXTRA_CHARS, stdin) != NULL)
   {
      /* Parsing the string to int */
      if(sscanf(str,"%d",&anInt) != 1)
      {
         sprintf(str, "Invalid input entered \n");
         exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
      }

      /* Creating the node using malloc(...) */

      if ( (new=malloc(sizeof(ListNode))) == NULL)
      {  
         fprintf(stderr,"\nMemory Allocation for ListInsert failed!\n");
         fprintf(stderr,"Aborting data entry!\n");
         break;
      }

      current = head;
      previous = NULL;
      /* Search to find where in insert new list node */
      while (current != NULL && current->data < anInt)
      {
         previous = current;
         current = current->next;
      }

      new->data = anInt;
      new->next = current;
      listSize++;

      if (previous == NULL)
      {
         head = new;
      }
      else
      {
         previous->next = new;
      }
   }/*End of input loop */

   /* Display integers in linked list */
   current = head;
   while (current != NULL)
   {
      printf("%d\n", current->data);
      current = current->next;
   }

   /* Deallocate memory used by list nodes */
   current = head;
   while (current != NULL)
   {
      next = current->next;
      free(current);
      current = next;
   }

   return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Here's the problem I have with it. In every example of linked lists I've seen so far online or in books, the definition of a linked list is given as a struct that contains only one item of data and a pointer to the next node in the list. The problem is that we've been given the following structure definitions to populate with data:

```
typedef struct price
{
   unsigned dollars;
   unsigned cents;
} PriceType;

typedef struct item
{
   char itemID[ID_LEN + 1];
   char itemName[MAX_NAME_LEN + 1];
   PriceType prices[NUM_PRICES];
   char itemDescription[MAX_DESC_LEN + 1];
   ItemTypePtr nextItem;
} ItemType;

typedef struct category
{
   char categoryID[ID_LEN + 1];
   char categoryName[MAX_NAME_LEN + 1];
   char drinkType;      /* (H)ot or (C)old. */
   char categoryDescription[MAX_DESC_LEN + 1];
   CategoryTypePtr nextCategory;
   ItemTypePtr headItem;
   unsigned numItems;
} CategoryType;

typedef struct bcs
{
   CategoryTypePtr headCategory; /* Pointer to the next node */
   unsigned numCategories;
} BCSType;
```

This does not fit in with all the examples I've seen. So in the "generic" code above, do I have to do everything above, but replace the "new->data" part with, for example, "category->categoryID", and "category->categoryName" etc etc for all the members of the struct in order to populate the entire linked list with data?

Comment: "In EVERY example of linked lists I've seen online or in books" -- but those are all simplified examples. You need to learn to think abstractly ... clearly there is no reason in principle that there can't be more (or less) than one data item in a node. And you haven't read very widely if you've never seen such a thing ... examples are posted here at SO all the time.

Comment: Look at it very closely. You have a means to have them all wrapped up together thus allowing for a singular node link.

Comment: *but replace the "new->data" part with, for example, "category->categoryID", and "category->categoryName"* -- no, you don't have to replace anything ... the structures you were given already have all the "next" pointers they need, in the CategoryTypePtr and ItemTypePtr members.

Comment: @ Jim Balter but when I try to use the code, the compiler tells me that there's no member "data" in the structure, etc, so I must have to use names of members of individual structs instead of generic variables.

Comment: Like I said, the structures contain everything you need ... and that does not include a `data` member ... again, that's just a *simplified example*. " so I must have to use names of members of individual structs instead of generic variables" -- you must use the names of the structs and the names of their members that you were given. I don't know what you mean by "generic variables" ... "data" is *just an example*. Professional programmers rarely use meaningless names like that, they use meaningful names like in the struct definitions you were given.

Comment: Addendum: There are some linked list *libraries* that can handle arbitrary data and so they have "generic" `void*` pointers called `data`, but you aren't writing a library, you're writing an application that has specific data structures.

Comment: "when I try to use the code" -- I don't know what *you* mean by "use the code". You should be able to compile that code ... `ListNode` does contain a `data` member ... and run it. But obviously it won't do what you need to do ... **it's just an example**, a demonstration of how to allocate, store into, print, and free a list. Use it as a **usage guide**, but it's a bad idea to try to start with that code and then modify it. Start your program from scratch, referring to that code for the basic ideas of how to deal with linked lists.

Comment: *but replace the "new->data" part with, for example, "category->categoryID", and "category->categoryName"* -- sorry, I misunderstood what you were asking earlier. Yes, you would use references like that in your code to access the members of your structs, instead of `new->data`.

Comment: `fgets(str, MAX_INPUT+EXTRA_CHARS, stdin)` : `+EXTRA_CHARS` is bad idea.

Answer (score 0):

Everything you need in the way of data structures was given to you. There's a top level item, `BCSType`, that leads to everything else. It has a linked list of categories with the head link in `headCategory`. And each `CategoryType` has a next pointer (`nextCategory`), and head link (`headItem`) to a linked list of `ItemTypes`, each of which has a next pointer, `nextItem`. You don't need to add anything to these structs and should not (and you'll get graded down if you do). Now you need to write the code that reads the data from the file and creates instances of these data structures, using the example code as a guideline for dealing with linked lists ... but you have to think, and be creative, to apply it to the three-level structure you've been given.

The vital thing here is to learn by doing. Try to write such code and don't give up, but if you truly get stuck you can, as a last resort, ask another question here ... but be very specific when you do, and include your code and error messages and all other relevant information about what you expected to happen and what actually happened instead. And be sure to learn how to use a debugger, and use it, before posting such a question.

Comment: OK thanks. I've been at this for days actually, and I've written several functions to do all that stuff, but to no avail. I posted this question because I thought there was something fundamental about linked lists that I was missing that was tripping me up. I'll go back to the drawing board, maybe start again. My code has become too large and messy.

Comment: @LeeCarbusier I advise initially writing your code top-down -- write calls to functions with names that indicate what they need to do, then write one of the functions that you haven't written yet, and repeat. If, in writing a function, you find you made a bad assumption about how to carve up the functionality, then go back and  modify the caller -- that's bottom-up. But primarily work top-down.

Comment: @LeeCarbusier Please see my latest comment under your question ... I had misunderstood you and so our exchange went off in the wrong direction ... that was entirely my fault, as you were spot on. I'm sorry if I misled you.

Comment: @LeeCarbusier "to no avail" -- As I said in my answer, you should be very specific about such things. Is your code not compiling? Is it compiling but crashing, or infinite looping, or producing the wrong results? You can append your code and what errors you are getting to this question and you may get help with it ... SO encourages posting actual code.

Comment: @LeeCarbusier as Jim suggested a good top down through a simple list will get your list-confidence up. There is no magic in lists, they are one of the most flexible data-structures in your toolbox. Start with a simple one-data item/next struct. You will find you have 2 basic functions in list creation (1) `create-node` where you **allocate** the node (struct) and storage for any members that require allocation; and then (2) **insert-node** where you check if list exist (if not, then node is 1st node), if it does, then just set the `->next` pointers as required. Post back when stuck.